# How to implement DataTables pagination plug-in to non-table data?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, pagination, datatables

Hi i have implemented the [**DataTables**](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html) plug-in for my client side pagination. Since it's working fine with table data. But i want to implement this same plug-in for non table data also. In some places i have `list and div` formatted data (`<ul><li>ABC</li></ul>`) .

How to implement this to non table data? Should i convert the `li` and `div` into table formatted data to do this?

Comment: just use some pagination plugin , like http://www.jquery4u.com/tutorials/jquery-quick-pagination-list-items/ or http://itswadesh.wordpress.com/2012/04/19/11-jquery-pagination-plugins-you-must-try/

Comment: @Daniel- i asked how to deal with DataTables?

Comment: You said that you want to paginate some `li`... unless you change your  data to be represented as table , I don't think that datatables can help you